# Downloading games in steam for Linux through an internet with authenticated proxy

Tags: steam, proxy

In Windows, I login steam through my mobile phone hotspot after logging in I switch to my college WiFi and turn on proxifier to download games. I want to do the same on Linux but proxifier is not available. Can someone provide a method for Linux as I was successfully able to download steam games on windows with help of proxifier.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS